# Python: remove repeated values only if at end of list

Tags: python, list, nan

I have a python list where order of responses is important. I would like to filter out `nan` values only if they occur at the end of the list. I was wondering if there is an *efficient* way to go from a list like the following:

```
nan = float("nan")
responses = [1.0, nan, 9.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

To a list without any trailing `nan` values:

`[1.0, nan, 9.0]`

I know how to filter out all `nan` values using a list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
[r for r in responses if pd.notnull(r)]
>>> [1.0, 9.0]
```

But can't think of a straightforward way to filter out `nan` values at the end without converting everything to strings and using regular expressions. I could do that, but am concerned about performance, which is an issue because it will be performed several hundred thousand times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while responses and math.isnan(responses[-1]):
    responses.pop()
```

Update: this isn't as fast as a straight up slice.

```
>>> timeit.timeit('responses = list(r)\nwhile responses and isnan(responses[-1]): responses.pop()', 'from math import isnan; nan = float("nan"); r = [1.0, nan, 9.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]')
1.3209394318982959
>>> timeit.timeit('responses = list(r)\nresponses = responses[:3]', 'from math import isnan; nan = float("nan"); r = [1.0, nan, 9.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]')
0.29652016144245863
```

Comment: > it will be performed several hundred thousand times.

Comment: With `responses = responses[:3]` you are creating a new list. Try timing `responses[:] = responses[:3]` or `del responses[3:]` (still, remember that the difference in timings is relevant only if `responses` is a big list)

Comment: By the way, be careful: by initializing the list with the `setup` argument of `timeit()`, you are initializing it only once. That is, `timeit()` will run your code say 10000 times, but the list will be modified only once.

Comment: @AaronDuke Properly updated to address Andrea's comment, a single slice is significantly faster. This answer is *not* optimal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no builtin function or method. But you can use a loop:

```
while responses and math.isnan(responses[-1]):
    del responses[-1]
```

As you can see yourself, this runs in linear time and uses no extra space.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse it and use `itertools.dropwhile`. This should work for any value.

```
r = [1.0, nan, 9.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x == r[-1], reversed(r)))[::-1] + r[-1:]
```

To filter just `nan`, you can replace `lambda x: x == r[-1]` for `math.isnan`:

```
list(itertools.dropwhile(math.isnan, reversed(r)))[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is iterate over the list once, and then find where the end sequence of `nans` begins. Something like

```
responses = [1.0, 'nan', 9.0, 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan']

first_index = -1
for i, val in enumerate(responses):
  if val == 'nan':
    if first_index == -1:
      first_index = i
  else:
    first_index = -1

responses = responses[:first_index]  # [1.0, 'nan', 9.0]
```

Then you can perform a single slice operation. It's a bit more verbose, than other solutions, but should be quicker.

Time Complexity

According [to this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), the slice operation is O(n), and iterating over the list is O(n), making this entire algorithm O(n) complexity.

Even better would be to iterate over the list backwards.

Comment: It'd be hard to come up with a solution that isn't O(n). What's the actual performance of this? Can you check with `timeit`?